# How do I make a GUI popup when I press a Button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am wondering how do I use onClick() or similar to make a GUI popup whenever I click on a button? Here is my current code. I am trying to implement the code into my shop script. The button the player would press is a button that says store. When the player presses the button named Store the script will make the actual shop show up. The Shop is not a separate scene. It is in one scene.

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Shop : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public int Money;
    public int Trap = 0;
    public int Weed = 0;

    public GameObject ShopLocation;

    void Start () 
    {

        Money = 100;
        ShopLocation.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void Clicked()
    {

    }

    void OnTriggerExit()
    {
        ShopLocation.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void trap() 
    {
        if (Money >= 20) {
            Money -= 20;
            Trap += 15;
        } else 
        {
            print ("Not enough money for trap!");
        }


    }

    public void weed()
    {
        if (Money >= 15) {  
            Money -= 15;
            Weed += 10; 
        } else 
        {
            print ("Not enough money for Weed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MethodMan "do a google search on how to dynamically create an Instance of a Form and how to show it" This is Unity.  He's talking about the Unity UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Button`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html) component can be used to do this. Register to the `Button` event with `Button.onClick.AddListener(()=>functionToCall()...)`.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Shop : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject shopToShow;

    public Button StoreButton;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        //Register Button Events
        StoreButton.onClick.AddListener(() => storeButtonCallBack());

    }

    private void storeButtonCallBack()
    {
        Debug.Log("Shop Button Clicked!");
        shopToShow.SetActive(true);
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        //Un-Register Button Events
        StoreButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    }
}
```

Remember, you must create a `Button` from the Editor and assign it to the `StoreButton` slot in the script. You should also put the UI to show when `Button` is clicked to the `shopToShow` slot.

Unity UI [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) for you..

Comment: I added that into my script. I can't add the button to the script. This is my current code. http://pastebin.com/BCNAzavZ

Comment: What do you mean that you can't add the button to the script? Attach the `Shop` script to a gameobject in the scene. Create a UI `Button` by going to GameObject->UI->Button. Now, drag the the newly created Button into the the script that is attached to your gameobject.....

Comment: I forgot to add a gameobject that is why.